# How to store unicode character in wstring on linux?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, unicode

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::wstring str  = L"\u00A2";
    std::wcout << str;  
    return 0;
}
```

Whys this doesn't work? And how solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because in the default C locale, there is no character which corresponds to U+00A2.

If you're using a standard ubuntu install, it is most likely that your user locale uses a larger character set than US-ASCII, quite possibly Unicode encoded with UTF-8. So you just need to switch to the locale specified in the environment, as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
/* locale is needed for std::setlocale */
#include <locale>
#include <string>

int main() {
  /* The following switches to the locale specified
   * by the LC_ALL environment variable.
   */
  std::setlocale (LC_ALL, "");
  std::wstring str  = L"\u00A2";
  std::wcout << str;  
  return 0;
}
```

If you use `std::string` instead of `std::wstring` and `std::cout` instead of `std::wcout`, then you don't need the `setlocale` because no translation is needed (provided the console expects UTF-8).